# Use Companion object in kotlin android is a good practice?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have ever used Java to programming in android, but a few weeks ago I started to learn kotlin, when I use Java I tried to use object oriented approach and use the less possible static objects or instances, so when I see some materials in internet about some implementations of consume web services in kotlin I see something like this:

```
/*call of method from activity*/
val message = WebServiceTask.getWebservice(getString(R.string.url_service))

/*Class to do the call to webservice*/
class WebServiceTask {
    companion object {
        fun getWebService(url: String): WebServiceResponse {
            val call =
                RetrofitInstance.getRetrofit(url).create(ApiService::class.java).getList()
                    .execute()
            val webServiceResponse = call.body() as WebServiceResponse
            return user
        }
    }
}
/*Class to get Retrofit instance*/
class RetrofitInstance {
    companion object{
        fun getRetrofit(url: String): Retrofit {
            return Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(url)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build()
        }

    }
}
```

Like you see i use companion object in two classes and according to i read companion object is equivalent to static instance in java, so my question is:
 is this code following object oriented programming?, this aproach is recommended?, in case that answer is no and which is the best implementation for this code in object oriented

Comment: Should perhaps look into dependency injection like kodein (https://github.com/Kodein-Framework/Kodein-DI) or dagger (https://github.com/google/dagger) if you don't to use companion objects, generally they aren't going to affect you much if you do use them but it would be better not to

Comment: `companion object` is how you define `static` variables/methods in Kotlin. You are not supposed to create a new instance of Retrofit / ApiService each time you execute a request, however.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, `companion object` is Kotlin's equivalent of `static` members in Java. Everything that applies to `static`, applies to `companion object` as well.

The use of `companion object` depends on how it interacts with the state of class's object.

If you are using some methods which are totally [Pure functions](https://www.sitepoint.com/functional-programming-pure-functions/) Or Some final values which you need to provide access to outside the class itself, in that case using companion object makes total sense.

It is **recommended for the above conditions** because it does not interfere with the state of the class's object.

**So, for the given code snippet it is a valid use of `companion object`.**

Observe that methods inside `companion object` do not interact with something which is not passed to them as parameters. Everything that you see is created/initialized or used inside the methods only, Just the result it gets out.

**Note:**
However, if your `companion object` members(values or functions) interfere with the state of the object, it will cause leaks, which will lead you to troubles you have never faced before.

Comment: @Joshi: _Yes, `companion` object is Kotlin's equivalent of `static` members in Java._ 

**Careful**: a `companion` object can inherit a class or interfaces — something that is not viable in Java static members. So, if you need Java-interoperable code, the solution is `@JvmStatic` functions and `@JvmStatic` properties. By annotating a `companion` object’s members with `@JvmStatic`, you will gain better Java interoperability.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is equivalent to static. No, it is not recommended, as it leads to problems with mocking for testing, for example.